# how to create doctrine mongodb connections via DriverManager

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, dbal, doctrine-mongodb

Is there a way to create mongodb connection using doctrine's DriverManager::getConnection() method? Most of examples use yaml file to configure connections. I am looking for a way to make doctrine-mongodb connections only with php code.

Answer (score 2):

[`Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php) is not related to the [doctrine/mongodb](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb) library. DBAL is an analogous to doctrine/mongodb in that they're both database abstraction layers w/o the modeling aspect, but DBAL is specific to SQL drivers (e.g. PDO, DB2).

In DBAL, there are various driver classes, and the manager class merely abstracts their construction. For doctrine/mongodb, there is no need for a manager since MongoDB connections all use the PECL driver's own [MongoClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) class. Constructing a `Doctrine\MongoDB\Connection` instance will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Doctrine ODM Introduction docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html), this seems to be the correct way:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Doctrine\MongoDB\Connection;

$connection = new Connection();
$dm = DocumentManager::create($connection, $config);
?>
```